# Turning whole project into shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, formatting

I am trying to export a map project to a website which only accepts shapefiles. The current project has 15 layers of disparate types: shapefile, gpkg, MultipolygonZ etc.
When I batch convert to shapefiles, however, there is some loss: the line polygons describing certain areas seem to get merged into a single slab and so do not serve the purpose of indicating certain valuable information about land use.
How can I turn the whole thing into a shapefile or shapefiles that can be uploaded?

Answer (score 3):

Shapefiles are a very old data format, but they are pretty versatile if you prepare your data carefully.

So make sure your fields adhere to the limitations of a Shapefile:

- Maximum length of field names is 10 characters
- Maximum number of fields is 255
- Supported field types are: floating point (13 character
  storage), integer (4 or 9 character storage), date (no time storage;
  8 character storage), and text (maximum 254 character storage)
- Floating point numbers may contain rounding errors since they are
  stored as text

Ultimately I would remove any fields from your data that you do not need.

Then do export it out one layer at a time and troubleshoot any issues that come up.

Comment: Which data format are not the old ones, GeoPackage?

Comment: Yes, GeoPackage is a good recommendation. But pretty much all other GIS formats are new compared to Shapefile. The attribute storage component of Shapefile is dBase IV, which came out in 1988.

Comment: Thank you for an extension. Yeap, I think @Vince did once a marvelous answer on this topic.